# google python exercises

Tags: python

I'm watching the instructional videos on you youtube and started doing some of the exercises at http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class but I'm puzzled by the below problem in the string1.py file.
What I can't seem to understand is, what is the "s" in both_ends(s): doing?

```
# B. both_ends
# Given a string s, return a string made of the first 2
# and the last 2 chars of the original string,
# so 'spring' yields 'spng'. However, if the string length
# is less than 2, return instead the empty string.

def both_ends(s):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  if len(s) < 2:
    return ''
  first2 = s[0:2]
  last2 = s[-2:]
  return first2 + last2
```

At the bottom of strings1.py there are some functions:

```
def main()

    print 'both_ends'
    test(both_ends('spring'), 'spng')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

So how does the program know to substitute "spring" for (s) or is that not what it's doing? I can post the entire file if need be. It's only 140 lines.

Comment: This test function is maybe the answer, but I still don't understand how it works.`# Provided simple test() function used in main() to print
# what each function returns vs. what it's supposed to return.
def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = '  X '
  print '%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected))`

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions for specifics. Also the tutorial at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html is pretty good - I mostly learnt from it.

Answer (score 1):

'spring' is the literal string passed as a parameter into function both_ends(), and 's' is the formal parameter to the function. Replacing a formal parameter with an actual parameter is performed when the function is called.
The 'test()' function is just there to confirm that the function behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, the values you give the function are assigned to the corresponding arguments in the function header. In code:

```
def my_func(a): #function header; first argument is called a. 
                #a is not a string, but a variable.
    print a     #do something with the argument

my_func(20)     #calling my_func with a value of 20. 20 is assigned to a in the
                #body of the function.
```

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a variable that we presume to hold a string.  We pass `'spring'` in through as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`s` in `def both_ends(s)` is the parameter for the input string. The length of this string is checked with the call to `len(s) < 2`, and various characters in the string are accessed by position with `s[0:2]` and `s[-2:]`

Answer (score 0):

`s` is the parameter to the function, but you plug in real strings like `hello` or `world` into the function instead of just the letter `s`. Think of it like a math function: you have `f(x) = x + 5`. When you plug in a number, say `2`, you get `f(2) = 2 + 5`. That's exactly what happens with the both_ends function. To make it simpler, here's some code:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 5

f(2)
```

The way you plug into the function in the code here is the same way you plug a string into your original function.